# Proper way to inject a class that implements an interface using Hilt

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have

**BeatPlayer.kt**

```
interface BeatPlayer {
   fun getSession(): MediaSessionCompat
   fun playSong(extras: Bundle = bundleOf(BY_UI_KEY to true))
   fun playSong(id: Long)
   fun playSong(song: Song)
 }

class BeatPlayerImplementation(
private val context: Application,
private val musicPlayer: AudioPlayer,
private val songsRepository: SongsRepository,
private val queueUtils: QueueUtils,
private val audioFocusHelper: AudioFocusHelper
) : BeatPlayer {
 .........

 }
```

**MusicService.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MusicService :  CoroutineService(Main) {
   @Inject
  lateinit var beatPlayer: BeatPlayer
}
```

When I run it says:

**[Dagger/MissingBinding] BeatPlayer cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.**

So I added this:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class StorageModule {
@Singleton
@Binds
abstract fun bindBeatPlayer(beatPlayer: BeatPlayer): BeatPlayerImplementation
}
```

Now, I run, it says:

**error: @Binds methods' parameter type must be assignable to the return type hilt**

How to do it properly?

Comment: Your binding is the wrong way around, you need a method that returns a `BeatPlayer` and inputs a `BeatPlayerImplementation`.

Comment: `abstract fun bindBeatPlayer(beatPlayer: BeatPlayerImplementation): BeatPlayer`

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my question based on comment from @HenryTest.

**StorageModule.kt**

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
abstract class StorageModule {
@Binds
abstract fun bindsPreferenceStorage(preferenceStorageImpl: 
PreferenceStorageImpl): PreferenceStorage

@Singleton
@Binds
abstract fun bindBeatPlayer(beatPlayer: BeatPlayerImplementation): 
BeatPlayer
}
```

Now Provide BeatPlayerImplementation.

**AppModule.kt**

```
 @Singleton
 @Provides
 fun providesBeatPlayerImplementation(@ApplicationContext context: 
 Context.,.,.,.) = 
 BeatPlayerImplementation(
    context, .., .., ..,  
 )
```

OR

In **BeatPlayerImplementation**

```
 class BeatPlayerImplementation @Inject constructor(
 @ApplicationContext private val context: Application,
 .....
 ) : BeatPlayer {
 .........
 }
```

Comment: `fun providesBeatPlayerImplementation` you can just use `@Inject` on this class constructor, and Hilt will know how to provide `BeatPlayerImplementation`